# RVM setup, rake::doc, and "rake aborted! no such file to load -- initializer"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rvm

So I've wanted to install RVM for a while on OSX. I finally got it working after figuring out I had to download the latest XCode. I installed ruby 1.9.2 and used these commands to create a new gemset in rvm:

```
rvm gemset create rails235
rvm 1.9.2@rails235
gem install rails -v 2.3.5
```

Then I went into one of my old apps that used rails 2.3.5 and tried to run some rakes and any rake I run I seem to get this error:

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- initializer
```

Also, semi related, right now I'm trying to get rdoc setup. I've never used before and I'm typing in "rake doc::app" and I'm getting that same error.

The full rake with --trace is this:

```
$ rake doc::app
rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'doc::app'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
brenton-wejrowskis-macbook-pro-2:bizzark wejrowski$ rake doc::app --trace
rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'doc::app'
/Users/wejrowski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in `[]'
/Users/wejrowski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:111:in `invoke_task'
/Users/wejrowski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/wejrowski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/Users/wejrowski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block in top_level'
/Users/wejrowski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/wejrowski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/Users/wejrowski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `block in run'
/Users/wejrowski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/wejrowski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/wejrowski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/wejrowski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/wejrowski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

No idea what to do next!

Comment: Could you please run the rake task that gives you the `no such file to load - initializer` error with the `--trace` option as well?

Answer (score 1):

Your `rake doc::app` error is most probably due to the fact that rake tasks only use a single colon (":") to separate namespaces and task names. Try running `rake doc:app` instead.